# Best practices for implementing Calculated Fields?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, parse-dashboard

I would like to get some advise on the best practices regarding implementing calculated fields in the schema.

Typical e.g.:

```
Class ABC contains fields: Field1...Field10

Field1...Field5 are 'static' fields.
Field6 = some operation(Field1,Field2)
Field7 = some operation(Field3,Field6)
Field8 = some operation(Field1,Field5,Field6,Field7)
```

Now, every time a create/update operation is done on any/all of Field1...Field5, fields Field6...Field10 need to be updated, in order.

What is the best (most efficient) practice to achieve this?

Also, is there some way (or on the Parse roadmap) to implement
Calculated fields in the Dashboard itself? And determine the formulas
there itself, while defining a field?

^ This has become sort of the prevalent way of defining Calculated fields in most modern database/database abstraction tools.

Hard coding every formula to detect a field/fields change, while maintaining the correct order of updates for the calculated fields seems to be too gargantuan a task for modern times.

Any advise on this is most appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Hi. The best way is through a beforeSave trigger.

Comment: @davi Hi, thanks for your response. Although, i was hoping a more technical answer, in the context of the Parse codebase (including BeforeSave triggers). Like how to detect changes in only 1 field? How to work when there are changes to multiple fields, all requiring different calculations for other dependent fields? How to best implement the order of update of calculated fields? And most importantly, how to make this entire process more efficient (possibly visual programming with the help of external libraries? ) ?

Comment: The usage of beforeSave trigger is pretty straightforward and the way to go. See en example here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#modifying-objects-on-save. You can compare the old object (available at request.original) and the new object (request.object) to check which fields have changed and you can set new values to multiple fields. Give it a try and let me know in the case you have any problem.